# ¿Como creo un diccionario dentro de una clase?

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo que crear una tabla con pandas.Dataframe, en la cual primero creo una clase y asigno los parametros que deben ser ingresador para poder imprimir la tabla.

¿Como puedo crear un diccionario dentro de una clase para poder imprimirla como tabla?

Aqui se crea la clase y los valores que deben ser ingresados en la tabla:

```
import pandas as pd


class registro(object):

    id_ = int()
    name = ""
    age = int()
    weight = float()
    sport = ""
    wins = int()
    loses = int()
    ties = int()

    def data(self):
        print(self.id_, "\t\t", self.name, "\t\t", self.age, "\t\t", self.weight, "\t\t", self.sport, "\t\t",
              self.wins, "\t\t", self.loses, "\t\t", self.ties)

    def __init__(self, id_, name, age, weight, sport, wins, loses, ties):
        self.id_ = id_
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.weight = weight
        self.sport = sport
        self.wins = wins
        self.loses = loses
        self.ties = ties
```

Aqui el usuario escribira los valores ingresados y se guardan en una lista para ser imprimida en la funcion "data()"

```
op = 1
personas = list()
num = 1
while op == 1:
    _id = int(input(f"ID de la persona {num}: "))
    _name = input(f"Nombre de la persona {num}: ")
    _age = int(input(f"Edad de la persona {num}: "))
    _weight = float(input(f"Peso de la persona {num}: "))
    _sport = input(f"Arte marcial de la persona {num}: ")
    _wins = int(input(f"Peleas ganadas de la persona {num}: "))
    _loses = int(input(f"Peleas perdidas de la persona {num}: "))
    _ties = int(input(f"Empates de la persona {num}: "))
    personas.append(registro(_id, _name, _age, _weight,
                             _sport, _wins, _loses, _ties))

    op = int(input("Desea agregar otra persona (1 -> Si, 0 -> No): "))
    if op == 0:
        break

    num += 1


for i in personas:
    i.data()
```

**¿Como puedo convertir la lista "personas" en un diccionario e imprimirlo como DataFrame dentro de la funcion "data()?**

O como seria una manera mas sencilla de crear un diccionario dentro de una clase y pasarle parametros

Answer (score 3):

No te puedo dejar un comentario porque no tengo suficiente reputación, pero igual esto te sirve para tu problema. Un diccionario es un mapa de clave-valor. Para tu problema, me imagino que tienes una lista de personas, y a cada una la identificas con un ID. Vas a tener un diccionario donde cada clave es el ID de la persona, y el valor sería el resto de información de la persona (que a su vez sería otro diccionario).

Yo personalmente haría un diccionario de diccionarios, de la siguiente forma:

1) Inicializa un atributo en tu clase que sea el diccionario.

```
self.__dictionary = {}
```

2) Para añadir las personas al diccionario, puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
def _add_dictionary(self, personas):

    for persona in personas:
        id = persona[0]
        self.__dictionary[id] = {'name':persona[1], 'age':persona[2], ..., 'ties':persona[7] }
```

3) Para imprimir los datos de TODAS las personas en el diccionario, lo puedes hacer de la siguiente forma:

```
def _print_dictionary(self):

    for persona_id in self.__dictionary:
        persona = self.__dictionary[persona_id]
        print("Nombre: " + persona['name'])
        print("Edad: " + str(persona['age']))
        ...
```

**NOTA**

Te pongo un ejemplo. Si tienes a las 2 siguientes personas:

id=6, name="Jorge", age=20

id=8, name="Diego", age=22

Al crear el diccionario y añadir esas 2 personas, self.__dictionary quedaría así:

```
self.__dictionary == { 6: {'name':"Jorge", 'age':20}, 
                       8: {'name':"Diego", 'age':22}
                     }
```

Si quisieras imprimir la edad de Jorge, harías lo siguiente:

```
diccionario_jorge = self.__dictionary[6]
# diccionario_jorge == {'name':"Jorge", 'age':20}
print(diccionario_jorge['age'])
```

O lo que es lo mismo:

```
print(self.__dictionary[6]['age'])
```

**EDIT: Tal vez estos métodos te sean más útiles para tu problema en concreto.**

```
# Convertir la lista "personas" a un diccionario
# Este método estaría fuera de la clase Registro
def _registro_list_to_dictionary(self, personas):

    dictionary = {}

    # persona es un objeto de la clase Registro 
    for persona in personas:
        # La clase Registro tiene un método _get_id() que devuelve su ID
        id = persona._get_id()
        # También tiene otros "getters" para el resto de atributos
        dictionary[id] = {'name':persona._get_name(), 'age':persona._get_age(), ..., 'ties':persona._get_ties() }
    return dictionary

# Convertir la información de la clase Registro en diccionario:
# Este sería un método de la clase Registro, y al llamarlo tendrías un atributo en tu clase que almacenaría el resto de atributos como un diccionario.
def _create_dictionary(self):

    self.__dictionary = {'id': self.id_, 'name': self.name, ... }
```

Comment: En este caso, personas sera utilizado en el main (fuera del class) y de ahi mandare a llamar a las funciones?

Comment: Es una opción. Puedes hacer un método en la clase que haga la lectura y el guardado en el diccionario al mismo tiempo, o leer el input en el main, construir la lista de personas y pasársela al método que te puse en la respuesta. Lo que quería era que vieras cómo era el funcionamiento de los diccionarios, la escritura y la lectura.

Comment: De todos modos, no entiendo muy bien el problema, tal vez porque nunca he usado Pandas. Veo que cada persona la instancias como un objeto de la clase Registro. Y una vez tienes todos los objetos creados, llamas al método data() para imprimir los atributos de cada objeto Registro. Donde quieres crear el diccionario?

Comment: Te he añadido una función que tal vez te sea más útil. Si creo entender mejor, tú tienes una lista de personas, es decir, una lista de objetos "Registro", y quieres que esa lista sea un diccionario. Haz que los atributos de tu clase sean privados e implementa los método "getters", o haz los atributos de tu clase Registro públicos o protected y accede a ellos directamente para construir el diccionario.

Comment: Deberia de tener una clase en la cual tenga los parametros que quiero agregar a mi diccionario de listas, pero no se como pedirle al usuario que ingrese cada valor fuera del main, que se ingresara dentro de cada llave del diccionario. Apenas estoy viendo Orientado a Objetos y por eso batallo un poco en la logica, estare revisando con lo que me ayudaste mas que nada para entender la logica de como se relacionan los datos